# Grails + Spring Security Rest + How to login

Tags: spring, security, rest, grails

I have created as sample rest application using grails and added a security using spring security rest plugin. I am trying to test it using rest client POSTMAN but getting 404 to '$MYAPP/api/login' and 401 '$MYAPP/api/login/' to when I sent post request with username and password as json in raw data.
I have followed all the blogs and stackoverflow but non of the things worked for me. Here is my code.
**In Config.groovy**

```
// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.example.api.auth.APIUser'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.example.api.auth.APIUserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.example.api.auth.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = 'InterceptUrlMap'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
        '/':                    ['permitAll'],
        '/index':               ['permitAll'],
        '/index.gsp':           ['permitAll'],
        '/assets/**':           ['permitAll'],
        '/partials/**':         ['permitAll'],
        '/api/**':              ['permitAll'],
        '/**':                  ['isFullyAuthenticated()']
]
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
        '/api*//**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter',  // Stateless chain
        '*//**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter'                                          // Traditional chain
]

grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.active=true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.endpointUrl = '/api/login'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rememberMe.persistent = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.useJsonCredentials = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.useRequestParamsCredentials = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.failureStatusCode = 401
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.usernamePropertyName =  'username'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.passwordPropertyName =  'password'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.useGorm = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.gorm.tokenDomainClassName = 'com.example.api.auth.AuthenticationToken'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.gorm.tokenValuePropertyName = 'token'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.gorm.usernamePropertyName = 'username'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.gorm.passwordPropertyName = 'password'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.logout.endpointUrl = '/api/logout'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.validation.headerName = 'X-Auth-Token'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.validation.useBearerToken = false
```

**In BuildConfig.groovy**

```
// security
        compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC4"
        compile ":spring-security-rest:1.4.0.RC5", {
            excludes ('cors','spring-security-core')
        }
```

Please provide feedback if something is wrong in my configuration or the way of testing using POSTMAN.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'when I sent post request with username and password as json in raw data'.   You have to pass a JSON structure as the body of the HTTP POST or it won't work.

For example in Chrome dev tools when I login and click on Network and then look at the Request Payload it looks like this:

{"username":"myusername","password":"mypassword"}

Also I'm not sure why you have '/api/**' in your interceptUrlMap - aren't you trying to require authentication to the API with your REST security plugin?   That implies that it's wide open by having permitAll.

Comment: Thanks for writing. Yes the POST request I sent for authorisation is same like {"username":"myusername","password":"mypassword"} in body. I also changed the '/api/**' in your interceptUrlMap to isFullyAuthenticated().

Comment: What I found that the issue was because excluded cors plugin from spring-security-rest. I will post my final code for reference for others which works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is my final config.groovy code which works.

```
// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'example.User'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'example.UserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'example.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
    '/':                    ['permitAll'],
    '/index':               ['permitAll'],
    '/index.gsp':           ['permitAll'],
    '/assets/**':           ['permitAll'],
    '/partials/**':         ['permitAll'],
    '/api/**':              ['isFullyAuthenticated()'],
    '/**':                  ['isFullyAuthenticated()']
]
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    '/auth/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter, -rememberMeAuthenticationFilter', // Stateless chain
    '/api/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter', // Stateless chain
    '/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter'   // Traditional chain
]
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.active=true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.endpointUrl='/auth/login'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.failureStatusCode=401
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.useJsonCredentials=true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.usernamePropertyName='username'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.passwordPropertyName='password'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.logout.endpointUrl='/auth/logout'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.useGorm=true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.gorm.tokenDomainClassName='example.AuthenticationToken'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.gorm.tokenValuePropertyName='tokenValue'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.gorm.usernamePropertyName='username'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.generation.useSecureRandom=true
//grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.validation.headerName='X-Auth-Token'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.generation.useUUID=false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.validation.active=true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.validation.endpointUrl='/auth/validate'
```

Comment: do we need to do any changes in url mapping file

Comment: Just need to specify the url mappings for your api. Here is mine            `"/api/correlations"(version:'1.0', resources:'Correlation', namespace:'v1')            
"/api/users"(version:'1.0', resources:'User', namespace:'v1', excludes:['delete', 'update'])`